# How to fix rygel upnp service discovery?

Tags: networking, dlna, upnp, rygel

I'm trying to use Rygel as a dlna/upnp server and renderer on a ubuntu laptop. It is not able to see anything on the network, and no other dlna software discovers it. There are other working dlna / upnp devices so I believe I can rule out the router.

Running in debug mode at the command line like this:

```
G_MESSAGES_DEBUG=all rygel -g 5
```

there are lines containing messages like this:

```
New network MY_SSID (wlp4s0) context available. IP: 192.168.8.127
```

which is the correct network, wifi card and ip address

In the config file the network setting is:

```
interface=
```

output from lsof filtering for my lan

```
lsof -i -P -n | grep 192.168.8| grep rygel
```

returns

```
rygel     25313           barry   14u  IPv4 25790052      0t0  UDP 192.168.8.127:1900 
rygel     25313           barry   16u  IPv4 25790055      0t0  UDP 192.168.8.127:37931 
rygel     25313           barry   44u  IPv4 25790056      0t0  TCP 192.168.8.127:41671 (LISTEN)
```

If I run another local client then it will show up on the that, so only localhost discovery works.

I have tried setting the network device to the network card in use, but it made no difference. I have not changed any other rygel config settings.